# Can $e^{-u^T \log(A) v}$, where $A$ is a positive definite matrix, be simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I am looking if it is possible to simplify the  expression
 \begin{align}
e^{-u^T \log(A) v}
\end{align} whre $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite matrix and $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^m $.  Here $\log(\cdot)$ is the matrix logarithm.

For example, can this be written in the form of a rational form or some kind of determinant of a matrix?

**Edit:**  Example for the diagonal case. If $A$ is a diagonal matrix, then 
\begin{align}
e^{-u^T \log(A) v}&= e^{- u^T {\rm diag}([\log(a_{11}), ...,\log( a_{nn})]  ) v}\\
&=e^{- \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \log(a_{ii})}\\
&=e^{-  \log( \prod_{i=1}^na_{ii}^{u_i v_i})}\\
&= \frac{1}{ \prod_{i=1}^na_{ii}^{u_i v_i}}
\end{align}

**Edit2**:
Here is another approach using matrix-matrix power 
\begin{align}
e^{-u^T \log(A) v}&=  e^{- Tr(  \log(A) v u^T)}\\
&=det( e^{-   \log(A) v u^T}  ) 
\end{align}
Now I found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Matrix-matrix_exponentials) that  $ e^{\log(A) B}=  A^B$, so
\begin{align}
e^{-u^T \log(A) v}= det(  A^{-v u^T} )=\frac{1}{det(  A^{v u^T} )}
\end{align}
Now can a term  $det(  A^{v u^T} )$ be factor somehow? 
For a scalar exponent, we know that  $det(A^k)= (det(A)^k)$, but here we are rather interested in the case of 
\begin{align}
det(A^B)
\end{align}
where $B$ is some matrix.  I guess this can be treated as the main question of the post.

Comment: Do you know anything about $u$ and $v$?  It works out really nicely for example if they are orthogonal.

Comment: @Paul  Unfortunately, can not assume anything about  $u$ and $v$

Comment: Can we use $A = UDU^T$ and $\log(A) = U\log(D)U^T$?

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, we can get an expression in terms of the eigendecomposition.  In particular, since $A$ is (presumably symmetric and) positive definite, we have $A = PDP^T$ for some orthogonal matrix $P$ and the diagonal matrix $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$.  It follows that
$$
\exp[-u^T \log(A) v] = 
\exp[-u^T \log(PDP^T) v] = 
\exp[-u^T P\log(D)P^T v] = \\
\exp[-(P^Tu)^T \log(D) (P^Tv)].
$$
Now, using your work for the diagonal case: let $\hat u = P^Tu$ and let $\hat v = P^Tv$. We have
$$
\exp[-u^T \log(A) v] = 
\exp[-\hat u^T \log(D) \hat v] = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^{-\hat u_i \hat v_i}.
$$

Comment: In fact, we can get a similar expression whenever $A$ positive definite, even if it isn't "symmetric and" positive definite. The case where $A$ fails to be diagonalizable requires some explanation, but a neat formula will still apply.